# natbib does not show the year

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm using `natbib` and `plainnat` as the bibliography style.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\citet{DIJKSTRA1959}   
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

where `mybib.bib` contains

```
@article{DIJKSTRA1959,
   author    = {Dijkstra, E. W.},
   title     = {A note on two problems in connection with graphs},
   journal   = {Numer. Math.},
   pages     = {269-271}
   year      = {1959},
   volume    = 1
}
```

I don't know why `\citet{DIJKSTRA1959}` does not print the year. The result is:

> Dijkstra
>
> E. W. Dijkstra. A note on two problems in connection with graphs. 
>   Numer.Math., pages 269271.

Is there a problem with the word "note" in the article's title?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You're missing a comma after `pages={269-271}`

Answer (score 4):

When you do

```
pdflatex file
bibtex file
```

you get an error from BibTeX:

```
The style file: plainnat.bst
Database file #1: mybib.bib
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 6 of file mybib.bib
 :    
 :    year      = {1959},
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Warning--empty year in DIJKSTRA1959
Warning--empty year in DIJKSTRA1959
```

and indeed the `.bbl` file shows

```
\bibitem[Dijkstra()]{DIJKSTRA1959}
E.~W. Dijkstra.
\newblock A note on two problems in connection with graphs.
\newblock \emph{Numer. Math.}, pages 269--271.
```

but only because of the error. If you add the missing comma at the end of the `pages` field

```
@article{DIJKSTRA1959,
   author    = {Dijkstra, E. W.},
   title     = {A note on two problems in connection with graphs},
   journal   = {Numer. Math.},
   pages     = {269-271},
   year      = {1959},
   volume    = 1
}
```

there will be no error by BibTeX and the `.bbl` file will have

```
\bibitem[Dijkstra(1959)]{DIJKSTRA1959}
E.~W. Dijkstra.
\newblock A note on two problems in connection with graphs.
\newblock \emph{Numer. Math.}, 1:\penalty0 269--271, 1959.
```

so that `natbib` will give the correct result for the citation, to wit

[image]

and also for the reference

[image]

### Moral

Always end fields in the `.bib` files with a comma.